# Drop Down Menu is Overlapping my Nav Bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm building a site for a client and I'm having trouble getting the drop down menu to appear clear below the navbar - instead it is overlapping the navbar, and if I increase the top margin of the drop down menu to push it below the navbar there is a gap between the drop down and the parent list item where the hover property to make it appear does not take affect.

I've created a fiddle of the navbar here - http://jsfiddle.net/s4dpby4v/1/

And you can view the live version here - http://japesfawcett.com/ps/index.html

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
   <div class="logo">
      <h1><a href="index.html">PAM SHAW INTERIORS</a></h1>
   </div>
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
         <li class="has-drop">
            <a href="#">WORK +</a>
            <ul class="drop-down">
               <li style="padding-bottom: 0;"><a href="#">COMMERCIAL</a></li>
               <li style="padding-right: 80px; padding-bottom: 0;"><a href="#">RESIDENTIAL</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="portfolio.html">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 75px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.logo h1 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    width: 25%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.logo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

nav {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    width: 60%;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: right;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 19px;
    margin-right: 75px;
}

nav ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: -5px;
}

nav li {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li ul.drop-down {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 2.5;
    clear: both;
    border-top: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}

nav li:hover ul.drop-down {
    display: block;
}

nav ul li ul.dropdown li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
}

nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CCC;
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 800ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 800ms ease;
    transition: all 800ms ease;
}
```

Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The reason is you have `position:absolute` for `.drop-down` class. It must be `relative`.

Comment: Ah, great! This has helped a lot thanks! The only issue is that now on hover it pushes the about list item to the left - any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.has-drop {position: relative;}
nav ul li ul.drop-down {width: auto;}
nav li li {width: 100%; text-align: center; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Will clean up you drop down, you just need to remove the inline styles that you have on here to fix up the list styles.:

```
<li style="padding-bottom: 0;"><a href="#">COMMERCIAL</a></li>
<li style="padding-right: 80px; padding-bottom: 0;"><a href="#">RESIDENTIAL</a></li>
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4dpby4v/6/

Comment: This is great - thank you! I was wanting the drop-down to have that full width effect, but I think this is going to be a much safer option!

Answer (score 1):

You can check with this css

```
.has-drop {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
nav ul li ul.drop-down
{
   margin: 27px 0 0;
}
```